# Scroll to top button inside a scrollable div

Tags: html

I have a fixed page (no scroll). Inside that I am displaying a table and other things in a div using overflow auto. I want to add back to top inside that div.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style=" overflow:auto; height:500px; width:auto;">
  <table>
     data..
  </table>
  <p>Some data..</p>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12" style=" overflow:auto; height:500px; width:auto;"></div>

Comment: Are you wanting to animate the back to top functionality with a smooth scroll, or do you just want to send the user back to the top of the scrollable div?

Comment: Just animate (or set) the `scrollTop` property of the element.

Comment: I want to animate to top of the scrollable div n not page.. My page is not scrollable only div